# I want to keep a reference inside an HashMap but I'm not able to specify correctly the lifetime

Tags: websocket, rust, lifetime

I'm using [ws-rs](https://ws-rs.org/docs) to build a chat app. I need to keep associations between a *Sender* and a *Username* but I'm having issues in referencing the *Sender* in my *HashMap*.

I'm 99.99% sure that Handler keeps the ownership of Sender.

I had solved this problem cloning every time the sender passing it to another thread, together with the username, via a mspc::channel but I wanna try to use smart pointers and reference.

Here is a Minimal, Reproducible Example:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread;

trait Factory {
    fn connection_made(&mut self, _: Sender) -> MHandler;
}

trait Handler {
    fn on_open(&mut self) -> ();
}

struct MFactory<'a> {
    connections: Arc<HashMap<String, &'a Sender>>,
}

struct MHandler<'a> {
    sender: Sender,
    connections: Arc<HashMap<String, &'a Sender>>,
}

struct Sender{}


fn main() {
    let mut connections: Arc<HashMap<String, &Sender>> = Arc::new(HashMap::new());

        // Server thread
    let server = thread::Builder::new()
        .name(format!("server"))
        .spawn(|| {
            let mFactory = MFactory {
                connections: connections.clone(),
            };

            let mHandler = mFactory.connection_made(Sender{});
            mHandler.on_open();
        })
        .unwrap();


}

impl Factory for MFactory<'_> {
    fn connection_made(&mut self, s: Sender) -> MHandler {
        MHandler {
            sender: s,
            connections: self.connections.clone(),
        }
    }
}

impl Handler for MHandler<'_> {
    fn on_open(&mut self) -> () {
        self.connections.insert(format!("Alan"), &self.sender);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dfc50413a1d23910811f48c1d16adb8f).

Ps: I'm aware that Arc doesn't guarantee mutual exclusion so I have to wrap my *HasMap* in a *Mutex*. I've decided to ignore it for the moment.

Comment: I don't think this design can work. You're putting references to Sender into a HashMap, so Rust has to guarantee that these references are valid, which is not true since your handlers are living in other threads. I suppose you could try to use a raw pointer to Sender and retrieve it in unsafe code.

Comment: Aren't senders meant to be cloned? What do you hope to achieve by using references?

Comment: @trentcl avoiding cloning the Senders between threads. Why do you say Senders are meant to be cloned?

Comment: @JPMoresmau also if I move the declaration of connections inside the "server" thread the problem remains. I just want an HashMap string obj. Why it should not be possibile?

Comment: I just mean they're cheap to clone and sending to a clone is the same as sending to the original (right?) I don't see why you want to avoid cloning one; this seems like exactly the situation where that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is unsafe. You're keeping in a map that lives for the duration of your program references to a structure that is owned by another object inside a thread. So the map outlives the the objects it stores references to, which Rust prevents.

Following on my comment, this code compiles (I've removed the factory for clarity):

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::{Arc,Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::ptr::NonNull;

struct MHandler {
    sender: Sender,
}

struct Sender{}

struct Wrapper(NonNull<Sender>);

unsafe impl std::marker::Send for Wrapper { }

fn main() {
    let connections: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<String, Wrapper>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new()));

    // Server thread
    let server = thread::Builder::new()
        .name(format!("server"))
        .spawn(move || {

            let mut handler = MHandler {
                sender: Sender{},
            };
            let w = Wrapper(NonNull::new(&mut handler.sender as *mut Sender).unwrap());
            Arc::clone(&connections).lock().unwrap().insert(format!("Alan"), w);
        })
        .unwrap();


}
```

This is using raw pointers (https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html#dereferencing-a-raw-pointer) and NonNull to be able to implement Send (see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21709 and https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1ce2532a0eefc60695663c26faddebe1&version=stable)

Not sure this helps you.

Comment: Thak you for your solution, but I would like to avoid unsafe code

Comment: I think what you're trying to do IS unsafe. You're keeping in a map that lives for the duration of your program references to a structure that is owned by another object inside a thread. So the map and the objects it stores references to have fundamentally different life times, which Rust prevents you to do. I'm new to Rust so maybe there are other, safe ways to do what you want, though.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to safely use this code - each thread can only safely use the sender that it itself owns, which makes the `HashMap` extraneous. It's not technically unsound because the pointers are never dereferenced, but it's unlikely to be useful.